# Templated class and type return type for a member function

Tags: c++, templates, generics, design-patterns

If possible, I would like to have a function in a class that returns a templated class, where the class and the class template value are template parameters. For example,

```
class AClass
{
public:
    template<typename ClassType, typename ClassTemplateType>
    ClassType<ClassTemplateType>* TestFunction() { return NULL; }
};
```

However, if I were to do something like this I will get errors such as

> error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
>
> error C2059: syntax error : '<'
>
> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
>
> error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Is it possible to do something as I have provided, and if so, how so? If it is not, why not and is there something else that could be suggested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for template template parameters is

```
template<template<typename> class ClassType, typename ClassTemplateType>
ClassType<ClassTemplateType>* TestFunction() { return NULL; }
```

Comment: Why is it `class ClassType` and not `template ClassType`?

Comment: @judeclarke the syntax is `template<template<typename [optional name]> [class or typename] [template name]>`, which is `template<template<typename> ClassType>` in our case.

Comment: Not true -- for template type arguments, either `class` or `typename` can be used, but for template template arguments, only `class` is allowed.

Comment: In his book Modern C++ Design, Alexandrescu uses the convention that template parameters are declared with `class` if they can be only a user-defined type, and with `typename` if they can also be a primitive type. Template-template parameters OTOH have to be user-defined classes.

Comment: @rhalbersma that's because there are no non-user-defined templates :)